# Django Many to Many 'QuerySet' object has no attribute 'members'

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, django-orm

First, here is my Location model. It has one ManyToManyField called members.

**Model:**

```py
class Location(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    # ...

    members = models.ManyToManyField(User, related_name="members")

    # ...
```

(Note, "# ..." replaces more fields)

And then in a view I did this.

**DetailView**

```py
class LocationDetailView(DetailView):
    model = Location
    context_object_name = "location"
    
    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        
        location = Location.objects.filter(pk=self.get_object().pk)
        context["members"] = location.members.all()
        
        return context
```

Error

```
'QuerySet' object has no attribute 'members'
```

Comment: Use `self.object` instead of `Location.objects.filter(..)`

Answer (score 0):

Your `location` is not a `Location` object, but a `QuerySet` that contains one `Location` object. Fetching this however is not necessary, you can work with:

```
class LocationDetailView(DetailView):
    model = Location
    context_object_name = 'location'
    
    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['members'] = self.object.members.all()
        return context
```

But in fact you do not need to pass the `members` to the context: in the template you can work with:

```
{% for member in location.members.all %}
    …
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the misake, it's

```
location = Location.objects.get(pk=self.get_object().pk)
```

and not

```
location = Location.objects.filter(pk=self.get_object().pk)
```

Comment: Please don't: this will make *three* queries: one to set `self.object`, one for the `self.get_object()` in your method, and finally a third one for the `Location.objects.get(...)` all retrieving the *same* `Location` object.